# OSGi BundleTracker: order of tracked bundles

Tags: java, osgi

I'm tracking OSGi bundles like this:

```
BundleTracker<Foo> bundleTracker = new BundleTracker<>(context, Bundle.ACTIVE, 
    new BundleTrackerCustomizer<Foo>(){

                @Override
                public Foo addingBundle(Bundle bundle, BundleEvent event) {
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void modifiedBundle(Bundle bundle, BundleEvent event, Foo foo) {
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void removedBundle(Bundle bundle, BundleEvent event, Foo foo) {
                    ...
                }
            });
```

Now, if a bundle B has a dependency A and B is started, then as I understand first bundle A will be activated. Is this correct?

The issue is that I'm sometimes get notified about some bundles before I get notified about their dependent bundles. So, how can I get notified in dependency order (if B depends on A, then first get notified about A then about B)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code dependencies (import package or require bundle) between bundles do not (in general) have any affect on the start ordering of bundles. The is some interaction between bundles using lazy activation.

So once A and B are resolved, starting B has no bearing on starting A.

The important thing to note here is that module layer dependencies do not affect the start order of bundles.

Comment: But if B uses classes from A, doesn't this mean that A has to be activated before B?

Comment: @Puce No it doesn't mean that at all. Bj's answer makes this quite clear.

Comment: Would it be the case tha bundle A would always get resolved before bundle B? If so, and you have an absolute requirement to get the notifications in dependency order, you could listen for the Bundle.RESOLVED events, record the order, and take that into account when you get the Bundle.ACTIVATED events.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand some OSGi details: so you're saying an active bundle B can access classes from an inactive/ not started bundle A, as long as A is resolved?

Comment: Resolving is an atomic process, it will resolve all bundles in one go. A bundle only gets started when all its dependencies are resolved.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this answers my question: Can a resolved, but inactive bundle A provide access to its classes through its classloader or does it have to go into the Active state first?

Comment: After some further reading it looks like its possible to load classes from a resolved but inactive bundle - the classes are there, the bundle itself just doesn't execute any of them on its own.

Comment: Please see further details and my current solution in the comments to Peter Kriens answers.

Answer (score 2):

Code dependencies have no influence on activation since all bundles are resolved atomically. So when a bundle gets activated, you're sure it only depends on resolved bundles. OSGi has a module layer  (with package dependencies) and a service layer. The module layer is static and the service layer allows you to express dynamic dependencies (with DS).

If you're struggling with start order you're likely not doing it right ...

Comment: Well, yes, I've read now that best practices dictate that one should not rely on activation order. The thing is I'm implementing an extension framework based on the extender pattern, JAXB and services (some of them dynamic): Bundle A specifies an extension point interface where extension points have to return their root JAXB class. Bundles which define extension points specify their JAXB classes and register their extension point implementation using DS. Bundle A listens for these extension points using DS. It also tracks Bundles and checks if they have an extension XML file.

Comment: If a Bundle has an extension XML file it gets unmarshalled using the JAXB root classes specified by the registered extension points. If a bundle Y specifies an extension XML for an extension point defined by bundle X, then Y also declares a dependency on X (because it uses annotations, annotations processor and JAXB classes provided by Y to create the extension XML file).

Comment: Now my assumption was since X (with an extension XML file) has a dependency on Y (specifing the extension point and the JAXB classes needed to unmarshall the extension XML file of X), Y will be activated before X. But the BundleTracker sometimes notfies about bundles in a different order.

Comment: So my current solution is to keep a list of bundles with extension XML files which couldn't be unmarshalled and process this list when a new extension point gets registered. I'm not 100% sure about thread-safety and memory leak issues yet, but so far it works fine.

Comment: Why not change the XML in the bundle to a service? Than it is easier to dynamically depend on it.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm doing in the end: I'm registering the unmarshalled objects as services. Consumers can use DS. So the extension become some kind of "data" services rather than providing some special implementation of an interface. I could maybe create a similar effect using name/ value properties but this isn't type safe. I'm open to suggestions however :-)